# Dumping the data into a pandas df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, elasticsearch

I am trying to get more than 10,000 observation from elastic search and dumping it into pandas data frame:-

```
es_index = "logstash-2018.08.26"
documento = "your_doc_type"


body = {"from": 0, "size": 100,
    "query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                 "bool" : {
                    "must" : [{
              "range": {"@timestamp" : {
                "gte": "2018-08-26T14:00:08.000Z", 
                "lte": "2018-08-26T16:00:00.000Z"

            }}
          }],
                   "filter": [
                        {"term"  :{"type" :"vx_apache_json"}},
                        {"term"  :{"api" :"viv_signin.php"}},
                        {"term"  :{"domain":"fnwp"}}




                   ]
                 }}}}}

res = helpers.scan(
                client = es,
                scroll = '2s',
                query = body, 
                index = es_index)
```

and when i am trying to get the value of res I am getting

```
<generator object scan at 0x10c89a938>
```

When i used the below code..

```
for i in res:
 print(i)
```

I am getting  data in the below format

[image]

I want to convert this into a pandas data frame like below:-
[image]

Comment: post a sample output. How do u want your df to look like

Comment: Any reason not to use pd.read_json()? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: `pd.read_json(res)`

Comment: @jalazbe i tried and got this error "ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'generator'>
"

Comment: @RahulAgarwal . a normal pandas dataframe.. i edited the post

Comment: try this: pd.read_json(res,orient ='split')

Comment: @RahulAgarwal still the same issue "Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'generator'>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you a better way to do this.. I guess you are trying to get more than 10,000 records.. try the below way and you will get millions of records as well::-

first install

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
```

1.) Define your client

```
client = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:9200'])
```

2.) `search = Search(using=client)`

3.) Check total number of hits

```
results = search.execute()
results.hits.total
```

4.)`s = Search(using=client)`

5.) write down your query

```
s = s.query(..write your query here...)
```

6.) dump the data into a data frame with scan...Scan will dump all the data into your data frame even if its in billions so be careful.

```
results_df = pd.DataFrame((d.to_dict() for d in s.scan()))
```

7.) Have a look at your data frame and smile :)

```
results_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Store all the data in a variable and then convert that variable into data frame using pd.DataFrame(YourVariable).

Comment: can you please put that in example as theoretically i know but not able to execute